# Two fillings on the same object?

Tags: inkscape

I'm a quite basic user of Inkscape. I have a the following single path:

[image]

I want to use a different color for filling the bottom part. In other words, above the intersection the color must be blue and below it must be green. I don't know how to do it as I have just one single path, instead of two.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: You split the path into 2 paths.

Comment: How to do that without modifying the shape?

Comment: Insert nodes at the intersection.

Comment: and after that?

Comment: Copy object delete other half in one object and other in other.

Comment: It does not work. If I remove a node the whole figure gets modified (because the curvature)

Comment: Thats why you add a node at the intersection on both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method which uses a boolean operation.

1. Draw a rectangle around the shape, and do *Object > Lower to bottom*
2. Select the rectangle and shape, and do *Path > Intersection*
3. Do *Path > Break Apart*

Now each piece can have its own fill.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed an elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

If your figure is twisted in a single point, you can use the bucket fill tool, to colorozize only one part in a different color.